# utilize htaccess to rewrite all indexes

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

upon a 404 I want to set my htaccess file to utilize another file from another location in lieu of the missing file. The url must remain the same as if the file was in the directory & more importantly it must function as if it where the same location. So my main goal is to have a file directory without an index file. Is there a way to rewrite the file request to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but it's a good workaround:

Add your normal 404 error page to your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

And in the 404.html file:

```
$Current_Url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($Current_Url == "/Your_directory_here")
{
   require("index.html");  //The page that you want to show.
}
else
{
   //Normal 404 Stuff
}
```

In my answer, I'm assuming that your .html files are being parsed by php.